# Sleep/idle mode leads to Wi-Fi lost

Tags: android, internet-connection, sleep-mode

When I have internet connection, if I leave my Android wear device idle for  around 20 to 30 minutes, internet connection stops.

In my app, I have connected with third party server, so sleep/idle mode leads to lose the connection with the server.

How can I handle this situation?

My requirement: my app should be always connected with the server to receive notifications.

Comment: Do you have a partial wakelock in your app?

Comment: No,I'm checking whether making my app always connected with server  is good idea or once user come back to app after idle state,only that time make app to connect to internet?...which is correct way to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want real time notifications, you'll need a [`Partial Wakelock`](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) to keep the service running, plus a [`WiFiLock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) to prevent the wifi network from going down. If you don't need realtime notifications, you can use [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) or [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) or [`WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) or [`JobScheduler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) to schedule checks for new notifications, say every hour or so.

Note that if you use `BroadcastReceiver`, it is not guaranteed that CPU will stay awake when the broadcast is received inside `onReceive()`. However, if you use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`,the CPU is guaranteed to stay awake until `completeWakefulIntent` is fired. `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` has been deprecated in Android O, in favour of `JobScheduler`

You can also read [here](http://wangjingke.com/2016/09/23/Multiple-ways-to-schedule-repeated-tasks-in-android) about scheduling repeating events.

For devices with Doze mode:

> The system exits Doze for a brief time to let apps complete their
>   deferred activities. During this maintenance window, the system runs
>   all pending syncs, jobs, and alarms, and lets apps access the network
>
> If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use
>   `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` or `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`. Alarms set
>   with `setAlarmClock()` continue to fire normally — the system exits
>   Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

Refer [Optimizing for Doze and App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

Comment: How can I make internet to be available in Doze mode also?

Comment: Edited answer for doze

Comment: I'm not getting you.My requirement is ,"Don't disconnect my app from WiFi" even if it is Doze mode.How creating alarm will help for this?

Comment: You cant not let the app disconnect from WiFi in Doze Mode because wakelocks are ignored and network connections are suspended in Doze mode. You can however set periodic alarms to wake the device from doze and check for notifications. (Alarm doesn't refer to the one you use to wake up in the morning or use as a reminder, btw, in case you are confused)

Comment: So I can set broadcast receiver to check whether device is entering to Doze mode or not,If device enter to doze mode,Immediately wake android device (it will connect to internet automatically).Please correct me  if i'm wrong

Comment: There is no broadcast receiver to check if the device is going into Doze. There is an intent `ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED` which checks for idle mode, which, afaik, is sleep mode and not doze mode. Also even if you find a broadcast receiver and do what you intend to do, note that it will be very inefficient with respect to battery consumption. Also Android 8.0 brings Broadcast limitations. You can read about it [here](https://medium.com/@iiro.krankka/its-time-to-kiss-goodbye-to-your-implicit-broadcastreceivers-eefafd9f4f8a)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169654/discussion-between-kavie-and-anuraag-baishya).